# Hbase and apache drill storage plugin

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-drill, apache-zookeeper

I am unable to create a connection between the Hbase and the Apache Drill.I am not able to understand whether the issue is with Hbase or with Apache drill.

I am able to create the storage plugin in Drill.Here is the configuration that I have given.

```
    {
      "type": "hbase",
      "config": {
        "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "localhost",
        "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort": "2181"
      },
      "size.calculator.enabled": false,
      "enabled": true
    }
```

GUI of drill returned success.But when i try to query it from the drill, I am getting multiple errors.Right now I am encountering the below error.

```
 Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
```

I am pasting the hbase-site.xml configuration as well.I have got some node in /hbase blah blah error before and hence commented the zookeeper.znode.parent parameter.

```
    <configuration>
       //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its files.
       <property>
          <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
       </property>

       //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its built in zookeeper  files.
       <property>
          <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
          <value>/usr/local/Hbase/zookeeper</value>
       </property>
       <property>
       <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
       <value>false</value>
       </property>
       <!--<property>
          <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
          <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
        </property>-->
    </configuration>
```

The version of the Hbase I am trying to connect is 1.2.2 and both hbase, drill are present in the same machine.

Please help me in resolving this issue, if anyone had already faced this earlier.

Comment: Drill version.....?

Comment: Drill version I am using is 1.7.0

Answer (score 2):

In drill 1.7.0 and 1.8.0 some issue is there so you just try to install drill 1.6.0 version it will be work.you can go through this tutorials also.
     http://www.bogotobogo.com/Drill/Drill_Tutorial_Query_HBase.php